# How to create an instance of the EntityDescriptor class

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection

For testing purposes I need to create an instance of the [`EntityDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.entitydescriptor(v=vs.113).aspx) class. This cannot be done directly, cause the constructor is not public.

That's why I try use reflection to create the instance.

```cs
EdmModel model = new EdmModel();
var constructors = typeof(EntityDescriptor).GetConstructors(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var entityDescripto = constructors[0].Invoke(new object[] { model }) as EntityDescriptor;
```

I know, that the single constructor of the class takes one argument of type [`EdmModel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.edm.library.edmmodel(v=vs.113).aspx). But when I call the above code I the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Das Objekt mit dem Typ "Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel" kann nicht in den Typ "System.Data.Services.Client.ClientEdmModel" konvertiert werden.

This means:

> The object of type "Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel" cannot be converted into the type "System.Data.Services.Client.ClientEdmModel".

But I cannot find anywhere the class `ClientEdmModel`. Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Could you translate your exception to English please?

Comment: Of course. I added the english translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is quite clear on the problem, your object is of the wrong type. Start up a decompiler of your choice and you will see that the constructor you mentioned takes a `System.Data.Services.Client.ClientEdmModel` instance as argument. This class is also internal so you have to create an instance using reflection too. Here is a little example that creates the desired object.

```
var entityDescriptorType = typeof (EntityDescriptor);
//using .Assembly.GetType() on a type known to be in the right assembly
//is a fast way to get nonpublic types by fullname
var clientEdmModelType = entityDescriptorType.Assembly.GetType("System.Data.Services.Client.ClientEdmModel");

var clientEdmModelCtorArgs = new object[] {DataServiceProtocolVersion.V1};
var clientEdmModelCtor = clientEdmModelType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null, new[] {typeof (DataServiceProtocolVersion)}, null);
var clientEdmModelInstance = clientEdmModelCtor.Invoke(clientEdmModelCtorArgs);

var entityDescriptorCtorArgs = new[] {clientEdmModelInstance};
var entityDescriptorCtor = entityDescriptorType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null, new[] {clientEdmModelType}, null);
var entityDescriptorInstance = entityDescriptorCtor.Invoke(entityDescriptorCtorArgs);
```

Comment: Meanwhile I found a solution for me to: I call the constructor of the EntityDescriptor via refelction with `null`. Your answer is more elaborated. That's why I mark it as the answer.